# Searchbar not responding properly to media query

Tags: html, css, input, css-float, responsiveness

I have a navbar with four links displayed next to each other, and a cart button that is floated right.

I added a searchbar, which messed up the display of the cart button, but I seemingly fixed it's display issue with a negative margin.

However, now when the screen gets below 705px (when the searchbar would become a problem with resizing) and it switches to the mobile style navbar, the searchbar is displayed on the same line with the cart link. I cannot seem to get it to move to its own line.

**HTML & JavaScript:**

```
<script>
      /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <!--Nav Bar-->
  <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#merchants">Merchants</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <div class="search-container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" />
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <a class="right" href="#cart">Cart <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Move the class "right" to the right side of the page */
.topnav a.right {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid #6b6b6b;
}
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #eeff00;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* search bar styling */
.topnav .search-container {
  margin-right: -10px;
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type="text"] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

/* When the screen is less than 705 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 705px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav div {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 705px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive div {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: you want the search bar below the four links in a new line if the screen gets below 705px?

Comment: yes, when it switches to the mobile style nav bar, when the user clicks the hamburger icon I would like for there to be the links in a vertical list, with the search being displayed in the vertical list, on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the cart link should be displayed on the right, when the screen is larger than 705px, yet the searchform is still on its own line? 
You are not setting a style on the right class of the cart link, add a float:right to that. Your second media query is set to max-width, you need to set that to min-width.

Comment: everything is working above 705px, it's when it switches to the mobile style nav bar that all the links are displayed properly, in a vertical menu, each on their own line. However, the search bar for some reason is also displayed on the same line as the cart link.

Answer (score 0):

Add this four selectors to your CSS-File and the search-button will displayed under 705px on a own line:

```
  .topnav.responsive .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
   .topnav.responsive input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display:inline-block
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 14px;
  }
   .topnav.responsive .search-container button{
    float: none;
    display:inline-block
  }
```

[the solution if the screen is smaller than 705px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFs1P.png)

I hope this is the solution you were looking for